# Which is the meaning of "living in chop"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am reading a science-fiction short story and I met this sentence that I can't understand.

> "living in chop”

You can read the the whole sentence in the attached file.

What does it means?

[image]

Comment: My guess: they are using nautical metaphors for their airship. At sea, “choppy waters” are mildly rough seas, lots of small, “choppy” waves, like bumps in the road, and not “smooth sailing”. I suppose in the air, “chop” would be turbulence. They have a leak in their balloon, and until both the leak is fixed and the missing gas replaced so they can ascend, they will be in that part of the atmosphere which is bumpy and turbulent, aka “living in chop”.

Comment: @DanBron I think you could be right. Unless someone tells me different I think that it might be a term invented for the specific book and it could become clearer as the OP gets further into the book. Alternatively it could be a term that balloonists would understand but those of us with their feet permanently on the ground would not.

Comment: Thank you very much both for the answers. I guess that's the right interpretation.